# How can I change a Numbers graph x axis to go from the lowest value to the highest value?

Tags: numbers, graph

I'm graphing columns A and B, where A is the x axis. I have entries entered in A like so: `1, 3, 2, 4, 5`... and so on.

When I select A and B and make a graph, it seems like the x axis does not automatically arrange itself from the lowest to the greatest value, meaning the graph looks quite strange.

Is there a way to make the x axis graph the data as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`... instead of as `1, 3, 2, 4, 5`...?

Sorry if I am unclear. I will make amendments at the earliest opportunity if clarification is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort your data ascending based on the values in column A - the x-axis.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I don't want to sort the column. If your method is the only way, however, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Does it matter if the graph uses a sorted data set? Because if not, then just make a copy of the dataset using large() or small() and have the points in order only for the graph.

Comment: Right, I could do that. I'm just surprised there's no way to have it the other way. In Excel it sorts the x values automatically

Comment: I found that excel didn't sort automatically (may be down to chart type) which is why I came up with the second dataset with large trick - I wanted to add a datapoint into the array which showed the optimum solution and it had to be in order...

Comment: I see. Seems like you'd be the person to ask, then

Comment: There are many better than I on the excel stack...